# Is there a way to prevent sh/bash from performing command substitution?

Tags: c, bash, embedded-linux, sh

From a C program I want to call a shell script with a filename as a parameter.  Users can control the filename.  The C is something like (initialization/error checking omitted):

```
sprintf(buf, "/bin/sh script.sh \"%s\"", filename);
system(buf);
```

The target device is actually an embedded system so I don't need to worry about malicious users.  Obviously this would be an attack vector in a web environment.  Still, if there is a filename on the system which, for example, contains backquotes in its name, the command will fail because the shell will perform expansion on the name.  Is there any to prevent command substitution?

Comment: Use single quotes `'` instead. Bash won't substitute that. I.e. `sprintf(buf, "/bin/sh script.sh '%s'", filename);`. Then everything depends on what `script.sh` is doing. You might also want to specify `-r` for a restricted shell, but there are some limitations of what you can do in such shell, see `RESTRICTED SHELL` section of bash manual page for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could always reimplement system() using a call to fork() and then execv().

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/system.html

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering "unalias " in the system function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as C I will provide you with a C answer.  You will need to escape the filename -- create a new string that will be treated properly by the shell, so that things like `This is a file name` produces `This\ is\ a\ file\ name` or `bad;rm *;filename` becomes `bad\;rm\ \*\;filename`.   Then you can pass that to the shell.

Another way around this would be to run the shell directly with `fork` and one of the `exec` functions.  Passing arguments directly to programs does not result in shell command line expansion or interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

As sharth said, you should not use `system` but `fork` and `execv` yourself. But to answer the question of how you make strings safe to pass to the shell (in case you insist on using `system`), you need to escape the string. The simplest way to do this is to first replace every occurrence of `'` (single quote) with `'\''` (single quote, backslash, single quote, single quote) then add `'` (single quote) at the beginning and end of the string. The other fairly easy (but usually less efficient) method is to place a backslash before every single character, but then you still need to do some special quotation mark tricks to handle embedded newlines, so I prefer the first method.